# db2 equivalent of tsql temp table

Tags: t-sql, db2, temp-tables

How would I do the following TSQL query in DB2?  I'm having problems creating a temp table based on the results from a query.

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3
INTO #TEMP_A
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_1 = 1 AND COLUMN_2 = 2
```

The error message is:

> "Error: SQL0104N An unexpected token "#TEMP_A" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: ":". SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: If I run the error in DB2 i get the following error..."Error: SQL0104N An unexpected token "#TEMP_A" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: ":". SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: As it turned out, I did not have permissions to create temp tables.

Answer (score 20):

You have to [declare a temp table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html) in DB2 before you can use it. Either with the same query you are running:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.YOUR_TEMP_TABLE_NAME AS (
    SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3
    FROM TABLE_A
) DEFINITION ONLY
```

Or "manually" define the columns:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.YOUR_TEMP_TABLE_NAME (
     COLUMN_1 CHAR(10)
    ,COLUMN_2 TIMESTAMP
    ,COLUMN_3 INTEGER
)
```

Then populate it:

```
INSERT INTO SESSION.YOUR_TEMP_TABLE_NAME
SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_1 = 1
  AND COLUMN_2 = 2
```

It's not quite as straight-forward as in SQL Server. `:)`

And even though it's called a "global" temporary table, it only exists for the current session.  Note that all temp tables should be prefixed with the `SESSION` schema.  If you do not provide a schema name, then `SESSION` will be implied.

Comment: A little helpful note: you might want to have "on commit preserve rows" included as "on commit delete rows" is the default and that behavior may not be desirable.

Comment: @RichardMorgan Or have everything run on the same Transaction.

Comment: Does the first bit of code there just define the table or populate it? Why is there a select from table_a in the definition?

Comment: @Bizorke the `SELECT` in the first statement just gets the definition of those columns, and makes the columns in the temp tables with the same names, data types, etc. In (my opinion) a bit of shortsightedness, IBM doesn't allow you to define and populate a temporary table at the same time.

Comment: @Hogan he did say that he wanted a temp table based on a query you are running. However, I went ahead and edited in how you would do it "manually"

Comment: I was able to create the temporary table, and then I tried to populate it, (I had a message "SQL executed OK. Number of rows affected=1"), but when I made a SELECT, my temporary table is empty. Could you know what is happening?

Comment: I have found it! I need a ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS in the definition of the table

Answer (score 4):

maybe the "with" clause is what you look for:

```
with TEMP_A as (
  SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3
  FROM TABLE_A
  WHERE COLUMN_1 = 1 AND COLUMN_2 = 2
)
-- now use TEMP_A
select * from TEMP_A
```

Comment: Maybe make it clear this is a CTE and not a temporary table.