# SQL Update multiple rows from one DB table to another DB table

Tags: sql, join, db2, where-clause

I have a table of values in which I need to take 'n' number of columns and update another table only where the value has changed.

For example, let's say I have DB1.Table1 and DB2.Table2.
Table1 has columns A, B, C, D and E.
Table2 has columns F, G, H and I.

I want the values in B, C and E to populate the values in G, H and I - where A = F and B <> G, C <> H and E <> I.

I have tried using a JOIN and WHERE, but neither seem to work.

Comment: I want the values in B, C and E to populate the values in G, H and I - where A = F and B <> G, C <> H and E <> I.  

I should clarify this.

If B <> G, OR C <> H, OR E <> I, it will make the update for the relevant field.

Comment: Did you prefix your join with the database names like you have listed in the question? For example  `SELECT * FROM DB1.Table1 INNER JOIN DB2.Table2 ON Table2. F = Table1.A`

Comment: Since I have to mention the DB name and the table name, I tried using an alias, but I started getting errors with the way I was using it.  I wasn't sure how to alias the second table.

For example: Select DB1.Tabl1 t1 works fine.  But when I need to place the alias in the middle of the JOIN or the nested SELECT, I get an error.

Comment: Have you checked out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126560/can-i-join-data-from-2-different-db2-databases-like-sql-server-linked-database You will need DB2 Federation turned on for the cross DB joins. In SQL Server you could use a synonym which is the method I prefer, but I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in DB2

Comment: That seems a little deeper than what I'm trying to do.  I will have to find a roundabout way to do it.  Thanks.