# Storing results into variable or table where I can use it later

Tags: sql, db2

My SQL query returns 132 rows with 1 column, I want to store them for a later use.

I have been through many posts on StackOverflow. I am trying following but it wont help:

```
DECLARE @store
SET @store=(select paramkey from parameter.p1val2 where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey LIKE 'FI%')
```

Is it so I have to use a temp table to store all rows ? so I tried following

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table select paramkey from parameter.p1val2 where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey LIKE 'FI%'
```

IT gives following error

> An unexpected token "CREATE TABLE temp_table" was found following
>   "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  ""..
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.62.57 SQL Code: -104, SQL
>   State: 42601

Br
Sara

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Based on the error code I am assuming this is IBM's [tag:db2]. [edit] the question tags accordingly if that is not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [db2 equivalent of tsql temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422572/db2-equivalent-of-tsql-temp-table)

Answer (score 1):

I was using db2 and following thing actually worked for me, thankyou everyone

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (paramkey varchar(200))
insert into temp_table 

select substr(paramkey,3) from parameter.p1val2 where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey LIKE 'FI%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like :

```
select paramkey INTO #temp_table 
from parameter.p1val2 where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey LIKE 'FI%'

SELECT * FROM #temp_table
```

Use #temp_table later now.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, it would be

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo SELECT paramkey FROM ...
-- Now use it ...
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

for mssql server  temp table creation

```
  SELECT  * INTO ##tempTable FROM (select paramkey from parameter.p1val2
            where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey   LIKE 'FI%')
```

for mysql  temp table creation

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
   (select paramkey from parameter.p1val2
    where paramname = 'BANKHOLIDAYS' and paramkey   LIKE 'FI%');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable as SELECT * FROM originTable WHERE x=y;
```

DB2 has something similar as well

```
CREATE TABLE tempTABLE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM originTABLE WHERE x=y
) WITH DATA
```

Fairly sure other DBMS have that too with some syntax variations.